# Is it possible to optimize the query in which nodes have an optional relationship?

Tags: database, optimization, neo4j, cypher

There are organizations and applications within the software system. User actions generate log records. Log records (green) do belong to organizations (red) and may belong to applications (pink).

[image: Neo4j DB model]

Trying to filter the nodes by application and organization (both params are optional), I created the following query:

```
MATCH
(log0:Log)-[:GENERATED_IN]->(org:Organization),
(app:Application)<-[:GENERATED_IN]-(log1:Log)-[:GENERATED_IN]->(org:Organization)
WHERE ($orgID IS NULL
    OR ID(org)=$orgID)
AND ($appID IS NULL
    OR ID(app)=$appID)
RETURN DISTINCT
    CASE $appID
        WHEN null THEN log0
        ELSE log1
    END
    CASE $appID
    WHEN null then log1
    ELSE null
    END
```

I use 2 `CASE` expressions because Cypher returns only nodes which do not have relationship to `:Organization` as `log0` (though I expected all `:Log` nodes to be returned) and because there is no possibility to return several variables from the `CASE`, i. e.

```
RETURN DISTINCT
    CASE $appID
        WHEN null THEN log0, log1
        ELSE log1
```

This seems not to be a nicely readable and maintainable code (esp. keeping in mind there are a lot of other filtering params I currently excluded for simplicity), so is there any possibility to optimize this query?

Comment: "esp. keeping in mind there are a lot of other filtering params I currently excluded for simplicity" - are these params for filtering the same node or all of them filter a different node (similarly to appID, orgID, etc.).

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas some of them filter on `:Log` properties (creation time, text of change in case of renaming) and some of them filter based on relationships to other nodes (author of the change to `:User`, user permissions to `:Permission` nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can return a map containing 1 or 2 `Log` nodes, like this:

```
MATCH
  (log0:Log)-[:GENERATED_IN]->(org:Organization),
  (app:Application)<-[:GENERATED_IN]-(log1:Log)-[:GENERATED_IN]->(org)
WHERE ($orgID IS NULL OR ID(org)=$orgID)
  AND ($appID IS NULL OR ID(app)=$appID)
RETURN DISTINCT
  CASE $appID WHEN NULL
    THEN {a: log0, b: log1}
    ELSE {a: log1}
  END AS result;
```

Comment: In some _cases_, returning a list would also work and it is even shorter: `CASE $appID WHEN NULL THEN [] ELSE [log0] END + [log1] AS result`